# Why runtime error occurs on using character element in array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, structure, codeblocks

I am using Codeblocks IDE with GCC compiler.

I am trying to implement the array of structures with different types of elements in a structure.
Till now, every array of structure works fine. but when I use character type of variable as a structure element then I get a runtime error.
why does this happen ?
The code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( )
{
    struct book
    {
        char name ;
        float price ;
        int pages ;
    } ;
    struct book b[3] ;
    int i ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; i++ )
    {
        printf ( "\nEnter name, price and pages " ) ;
        scanf ( "%c %f %d", &b[i].name, &b[i].price, &b[i].pages ) ;
    }
    for ( i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; i++ )
        printf ( "\n%c %f %d", b[i].name, b[i].price, b[i].pages ) ;
    return 0;

}
```

I understood that this issue can be solved by using a whitespace before format string as " %c".

But in the case of a character array, I still get the same issue while using gets function.
the code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    struct Bookinfo
    {
        char bname[20];
        int pages;
        int price;
    };
    struct Bookinfo book[3];
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the Name of Book    : ");
        gets( book[i].bname); //This statement creates runtime error
        printf("\nEnter the Number of Pages : ");
        scanf(" %d",&book[i].pages);
        printf("\nEnter the Price of Book   : ");
        scanf(" %d",&book[i].price);
    }

    printf("\n--------- Book Details ------------ ");

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("\nName of Book    : %s",book[i].bname);
        printf("\nNumber of Pages : %d",book[i].pages);
        printf("\nPrice of Book   : %d",book[i].price);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"%c` put space before `%` (for skip white spaces)  --> `" %c`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `%c` is reading the newline at the end of the previous line. Then `%f` is trying to parse the name, but it's failing because the name isn't a number.

Comment: @Barmar On runtime It successfully accepts values for b[0] but for later array elements ie b[1] and b[2] it doesn't.

Comment: On an unrelated note, why do you put the newline at the *beginning* of the string you print? Remember that `stdout` (which `printf` is writing to) is by default line-buffered, which means it will flush on newline. So by having the newline at the beginning you will flush the *previous* (if any) line, not the current. And the last line will only be written once when the program exits (and without a newline, so if you run from the command-line the output will look like part of the prompt).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes it did worked by providing a space. Can you please elaborate what effect white spaces have in " %c

Comment: Space in the format will skip the white space(tab space newline..) character. see [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I still didn't get it from the link provided by you. Would you please give a lucid explanation?

Comment: the newline of previous input  consume by that specifies space in format,

Comment: @DavidLively: Did you write a full lexer for such simple tasks?

Comment: @Olaf I rarely get an access violation using `std::cin`. I'm a big fan of straight C, but prof's need to teach better if they expect their students to be able to function. (Ha. Function.) Then again, stl on an 8051 never did anyone any favors...

Comment: @DavidLively: That is nonsense! There is no `cin` etc. in C and there are very good reasons to use C. I strongly doubt you ever programmed professionally embedded systems or at OS-level. And I'm not talking about 8051. And no, it is not all about functioning. That's what the MBAs spread.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `%c` is not just for reading visible characters, it will read any character, including control characters.

If your input looks like this:

```
a 1.23 5
b 2.34 10
c 10.98 7
```

The first line will read `a` into `book[0].name`, `1.23` into `book[0].price`, and `5` into `book[0].pages`. So reading the first line works correctly.

At this point, the next character in the input is the newline character at the end of the first line. So when you perform the next `scanf`, it will read `\n` into `book[1].name`. Then it tries to read `b` into `book[1].price`, but it fails because this isn't a valid floating point number.

The solution is to put a space before `%c` in the format string. This tells `scanf` to skip over any whitespace characters before trying to read something with the `%c` format. So it will skip over the newlines, and put the first visible character into `books[i].name`.

```
    scanf ( " %c %f %d", &b[i].name, &b[i].price, &b[i].pages ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Char is for just one character, like 'A' or 'B'.
You might see some undefined behaviour if you enter a string like 'ABCD' instead.
Based on the name of the variable 'name' it appears that you want a string.
In which case you would need to modify the structure to have an array of chars.

However as mentioned in the comments, more information about the runtime error will help debug, as will the inputs you are providing.

Comment: I used the same program with array of characters and it worked fine.
PS. I'm giving values as single characters only.

Comment: Hmmm.. then there might be something to do with the way scanf works, what are the inputs exactly?

Comment: It is giving errors for any random inputs. like
a
1
4

g
5
6 etc

Comment: @PiyushMalviya - _I used the same program with array of characters and it worked fine_  Two comments: 1) see other answer for relevant comments on your original questions.  2) This answer mentions _[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)_.  Where, as the link explains, means that anything is possible from run to run, even seemingly normal execution.  But eventually, your program can crash.